# Origen de la abreviatura "X" para referirse al miércoles

Tags: historia, abreviaturas, tiempo

En muchos calendarios que abrevian las denominaciones de los días de la semana usando una letra, se usa la 'X' para el miércoles con el fin de evitar confundir el día con el martes. Buscando el origen de la abreviatura, [algunos](https://blogs.20minutos.es/becario/2009/11/15/aapor-quao-abreviamos-miaorcoles-con-letra-x/) [blogs](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/por-que-al-miercoles-se-le-abrevia-con-una-x/) cuentan la historia de que se hace en honor al rey Alfonso X, quien mucho antes de la aparición de la RAE se preocupó por dar esplendor al idioma.

Sin embargo, también he llegado a otras historias, como una que dice que dado que "miércoles" viene del dios [Mercŭrĭus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=mercurius&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), y este nombre a su vez proviene del latín *[merx](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=merx&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* 'mercancía', para distinguir *[Mars](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=mars&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* de *merx* se usó dicha X para el día de la semana. Sin embargo, esto habría dado lugar a que la abreviatura existiera ya en latín ([cuestión lanzada](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11041/2646) en Latin Language).

Hay una tercera historia que dice que podría provenir de la abreviatura *Xpo* para "Cristo", y que se empezara a usar en los Miércoles de Ceniza.

Para tratar de ver cuál de las historias es la correcta, me gustaría saber:

- ¿Desde cuándo se lleva usando esta abreviatura en español?
- ¿Qué decían los primeros textos que la usaban acerca del origen de la misma?

Comment: @walen sí, esa era mi idea, pero incluso aunque así sea en algún momento se tuvo que originar, veamos qué dice la historia.

Comment: Su uso más temprano que he encontrado es de [1968](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8YgXAQAAIAAJ&q=L+M+X+J+V+S+D), que apoya la hipótesis que viene de una costumbre de los taxistas de la década de 1970: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/abréviation-abreviatura-l-m-x-j-v-s-d-horario-días.2195749/#post-12327679 https://jmgalvezc.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/la-x-del-miercoles-y-los-taxis-de-madrid/

Comment: That book in french language effectively destroys the absurd, *cañí* and ridiculously chauvinist theory that the use is related in any way to king Alfonso X. Ask the french, italian, german languages SE sites for earlier examples of the phenomenon, in order to consider the 'merx' theory good. It's the most sensible theory.

Answer (score 2):

No creo que haya una respuesta específica a tu pregunta. La Internet puede estar plagada de muchas historias falsas queriendo dar explicaciones a las cosas para tener suscriptores o seguidores. Lo mejor sería asistir a una biblioteca de tu municipalidad donde puedas encontrar textos antiguos basados en gramática u ortografía.

Sin embargo, aquí te traigo otra posible explicación basada en mi propia experiencia. La primera vez que vi la X fue en las primeras versiones de los sistemas operativos MS DOS y Windows (antes del 95) y en la informática en general.

Es bien sabido que la gente que estudió en el M.I.T a finales de los 80s se percataron que por restricciones de ancho de banda y capacidad de almacenamiento se imprimian los calendarios con el formato de un caracter en Inglés MTWRFSU. Si aprecias bien, en el Inglés también hay ese conflicto entre Martes (Tuesday) y Jueves (Thursday) como también entre Sábado (Saturday) y Domingo (Sunday) por lo que remplazaron Jueves con R y Domingo por U. Creo que es la misma razón por la que en Español utilizaron la X por Miércoles LMXJVSD.

El ISO 8601 indica que los días de la semana deben comenzar por Lunes y que las abreviaturas de los días de la semana deben ser de 3 caracteres [ISO - ISO 8601 Date and time format](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html)

Sin embargo, el fundeu explica que los días de la semana no tiene una abreviatura específica y que queda a criterio del autor. [Abreviaturas de los meses y los días de la semana](https://www.fundeu.es/escribireninternet/abreviaturas-de-los-meses-y-los-dias-de-la-semana/)

Espero que si algún día encuentras la respuesta con bibliografía, ayudaría a toda la comunidad si la compartes.

Comment: En los comentarios a la pregunta ukemi localizó un texto de 1968 que incluía la X. En búsquedas propias he visto que la X se empezó a usar en esa década probablemente, antes de que los ordenadores llegaran a la gente en general.

Comment: Entre todas las teorías de la Web, me quedaría con la de Alfonso X ya que es la más difundida, pero en el fundeu dice que es una utilización particular de los taxis para evitar confusiones con Martes. Preferiría aceptar la verdad de una fuente oficial hispana. Sin embargo, a lo que quería llegar con mi respuesta es que su nacimiento sea simplemente la creación de una persona común (como un taxista) a la que se le ocurrió utilizar una X y de ahí todos lo copian como si fueran los memes de la época.